# Xamarin Forms - Html2Xaml converter issue with span TapGestureRecognizer command

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xslt, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to convert custom html text in FormattedString xaml for any label. There, I have an `<a/>` tag where it will convert to an span with TapGestureRecognizer:

```
<xsl:template match="A | a" priority="9">
    <Span TextDecorations="Underline">
        <xsl:attribute name="Text">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <Span.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{{Binding PopupContentCommand}}">
                <xsl:attribute name="CommandParameter">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@href" />
                </xsl:attribute>
            </TapGestureRecognizer>
        </Span.GestureRecognizers>
    </Span>
</xsl:template>
```

**The converter is working well, the issue is that this command binding is not raising.** When we load `new FormattedString().LoadFromXaml(xaml)` the converted html to xaml, the command appears to have binding:

[image]

But this binding is not raising. After that I try to Clear the GestureRecognizers and create an new TapGestureRecognizer adding it again. But this didn't work neither. The BindingContext appears to be the correct one too.

[image]

This is done by binding an attached property:

```
<Label attachedProperties:Properties.Html="{Binding HtmlText}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it was a simulator issue. Because in the real devices this raise without problem.